# Access page number on each draw of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a data-table initialized as follows:

```
var table = $('#datatable').Datatable({
  fnDrawCallback: function() {
    alert(pageNumber it is currently on);
  }
});
```

How can I get page number per draw of Datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this link:- https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnPagingInfo

***You have to register `fnPagingInfo()` function first and then you can happily use it like below:-***

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
{
    return {
        "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
        "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
};
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "fnDrawCallback": function () {
          var pageno = parseInt(this.fnPagingInfo().iPage)+1;
          alert( 'Now on page :- '+pageno  );
        }
      } );
  } );

var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  lengthChange: true,
  lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
  ordering: true,
  pageLength: 5,
  searching: true,
  paging: true,
  fnDrawCallback: function() {
    var pageno = parseInt(this.fnPagingInfo().iPage)+1;
          alert( 'Now on page :- '+pageno  );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<div class="well contentbox">
  <h2>Search Results :-</h2>

  <div class="tablesorter">
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-show-colums="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="20%">Name</th>
          <th width="20%">Profession</th>
          <th width="20%">Place</th>
          <th width="10%">Age</th>
          <th width="10%">DOB</th>
          <th width="20%">Salary</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand what mistake I did. I placed the fnPagingInfo initialisation function inside of document.ready(). Your solution works for me as well. I have marked it as the answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `page` property of the `page.info()` object to find the current page. Try this:

```
var currentPage = table.page.info().page;
console.log(currentPage);
```

Also note that your code is missing a `{` within the `DataTable()` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get current page

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
        pageNo = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage+1;
        alert(pageNo);
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( I think that's for an earlier version of datatables?

Comment: You didn't mention the version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The current working version, whichever it is, is what I am using. Is that code supposed to be compatible with the current version?